# Trigger Modal in view with data from another view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, binding, modal-dialog, swiftui, state

Since a few days, I've been trying to display a view from another view using the data from the first view, however the data doesn't seem to be transmitted.

The goal is to display a modal, however this one can't be displayed only on the "alert" variable is set to true.

Here is an example below:

Login.swift

```
struct Login: View {
    @State var mail = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @State var alert = false
    @State var error = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    TextField("Enter Email Address", text: self.$mail)
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
                Divider()
                
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        SecureField("Password", text: self.$password)
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                self.verify()
            }) {
                Text("LOGIN")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func verify() {
        if self.mail != "" && self.password != "" {

        } else {
            self.error = "Please fill all the contents properly"
            self.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

HomeLogin.swift

```
struct HomeLogin: View {
    @State var index = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if self.index == 0 {
                    Login()
                } else {
                    Register()
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            
            if Login().alert {
                ErrorView(alert: Login().$alert, error: Login().$error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ErrorView.swift

```
struct ErrorView: View {
    
    @Binding var alert: Bool
    @Binding var error: String
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {_ in
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Error")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                
                Text(self.error)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                    .padding(.top)
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.alert.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120)
                }
                .background(Color("Color"))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 25)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 25)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 70)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.35).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

In order: When I launch my application, I'm on the HomeLogin view, which will load the Login view, in this Login view, if the fields are empty when I click on `LOGIN`, then I put an error message to my variable and I `.toggle()` alert, then in HomeLogin, if alert is a true, I make ErrorView appear.

However, it doesn't work, I've tried a lot of things, but nothing works! I'm a bit blocked and I'd like to solve these little modal errors before continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use an `@ObservedObject` (or an `@EnvironmentObject`) to keep a state for your views:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var error = ""
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var appState = AppState()
    ...
}
struct ErrorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState
    ...
}
struct Login: View {
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState
    ...
}
```

Then in all your views you can use `AppState` properties.

Instead of:

```
Text(self.error)
...
self.alert.toggle()
```

you'd do:

```
Text(self.appState.error)
...
self.appState.alert.toggle()
```

Note that you'd need to pass `AppState` to your views:

```
Login(appState: appState)
...
ErrorView(appState: appState)
```

This all is assuming you do *really* have a need to present a custom alert from another view. I'd recommend you take a look at [Alerts, ActionSheets, Modals and Popovers in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/07/24/alerts-actionsheets-modals-and-popovers-in-swiftui/) and decide if it's not easier to just present an alert.

Comment: Hello pawello2222,

Thank you very much, it works, indeed, I really needed to present an alert from another view, I will still read about the links you sent me.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to show the ErrorView from HomeLogin instead of Login since you all the data that you want there, but if it's just a modal for the error that you want to show, simply remove this:

```
if Login().alert {
    ErrorView(alert: Login().$alert, error: Login().$error)
}
```

and change the button in the Login view to:

```
Button(action: {
   self.verify()
}) {
   Text("LOGIN")
}.sheet(isPresented: $alert) {
   ErrorView(alert: $alert, error: $error)
}
```

Comment: Hello Lualdi Dylan,

I display ErrorView in HomeLogin, because the login view contains only the inputs, so if I trigger ErrorView in Login, the view will appear center in the Login view and not in the HomeLogin view.

Thank you for your response !